# Using a blade file for a template?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-5.4

I have a blade file that I wish to use as a vue component. So in the .vue file I would normally have it coded as:

```
<template>
....
</tempalte>
....rest of vue file
```

But how can I use a blade file for a template?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is put the html in your vue-component file like:

```
<template>
...put your html here
</tempalte>
```

and then in the blade file insert the vue compoent like

```
@extends('layouts.app')
  <vue-component> </vue-component>
@section('content')
```

Comment: Thanks but doesnt answer the question, I don;t want the html in the vue file.

Comment: Oh! sorry. That wasn't stated in your question. I'm not sure that is anyway supported.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `slot` in the vue file to insert the html passed from blade view.

**Blade file:**

```
<vue-component>All your html to be passed goes here</vue-component>
```

**Vue file:**

```
<template>
    <slot></slot>
</template>
```

You can read more about it in the official documentation for single slot [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Single-Slot).

Comment: Thanks but doesnt work, vue file is not attaching to html component.

Comment: Are you getting any errors on the console/terminal? I've been using similar code for passing some rendered html from blade template to vue and it works.

Comment: Yes, just errors that it cant find the methods on the vue component.

Comment: could you perhaps update the question with what you tried? I am unable to figure out what methods you're referring to.